# Python/Tkinter: Getting the full Event name?

Tags: python, events, tkinter

How do I get the full name of an event? For example, `Event.keysym` only shows "c" for an event triggered by `"<Control-c>"`. How can I get the "Control" too?

Comment: That's not the full name of the event anyway: it's really `<Control-KeyPress-c>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Event.state holds the OR'd together states of the modifier keys. So you could try something like:

```
modifiers = []
if event.state & 1:
    modifiers.append('Shift')
if event.state & 4:
    modifiers.append('Control')
# ... etc
print '-'.join(modifiers)
```

See [here](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/events.html#event-handlers) for more details.

Comment: EXCELLENT. I currently attend NMT and from experience I can say Professor Shipman is the king of all things python. Unfortunately, it is Saturday. Fortunately, ekhumoro is wonderful. This is exactly what I needed.